# searching sub string in string and check another string before that

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an array of number  strings 
for example  156983425
I want to search if it has '34' or not 
if it has '34' does it have 6 before '34' or not ?

thanks for your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `std::string::find` and an `if`. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go, use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find):

```
// Notice the double quotes
std::string::size_type position = my_string.find("34");
bool found = 
 ((position != std::string::npos) && (position > 0) && (my_string[position - 1] == '6'));
```

The `find` method returns the position of substring, or `std::string::npos` if it is not found.

The position must be greater than 0, because of the "before" requirement.

If both conditions are satisified, the character slot before the "34" is checked for '6', and assigned to a boolean variable.

Comment: What if `"34"` is found at position `0`?

Comment: The `found` variable is set to `false`, indicating that the requirement is not satisfied.  Since the `&&` operator has short-circuiting, the evaluation stops when a term evaluates to false.  Thus the last term is not evaluated with `position` is zero.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I've been overlooking the `(position > 0)` condition.